# Go through every possible combination of an array python

Tags: python, arrays, combinations

Say you got an array of 4 numbers. What is the best way to go through all the possible combinations? A start of the combinations would be:

1,2,3,4

1,2,4,3

1,3,2,4

1,3,4,2

1,4,2,3

2,1,3,4

etc.

Comment: Your answer is probably here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/python-code-to-pick-out-all-possible-combinations-from-a-list

Comment: @mrcheshire not exactly, what I want is all combinations of the 4 numbers in different orders. In that post they explain how every combination of those 4 numbers are listed, doesn't matter the order. So 1,2,3,4 is the same as 1,3,2,4. Which I don't want to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) is just what you're looking for:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> [i for i in permutations(range(1, 5), 4)]
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 4, 3), (1, 3, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4, 2), (1, 4, 2, 3), (1, 4, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3, 4), (2, 1, 4, 3), (2, 3, 1, 4), (2, 3, 4, 1), (2, 4, 1, 3), (2, 4, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2, 4), (3, 1, 4, 2), (3, 2, 1, 4), (3, 2, 4, 1), (3, 4, 1, 2), (3, 4, 2, 1), (4, 1, 2, 3), (4, 1, 3, 2), (4, 2, 1, 3), (4, 2, 3, 1), (4, 3, 1, 2), (4, 3, 2, 1)]
```

**EDIT:**
Or, as @wflynny pointed out, you can save the list comprehension by just calling `list`'s constructor:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> list(permutations(range(1, 5), 4))
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 4, 3), (1, 3, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4, 2), (1, 4, 2, 3), (1, 4, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3, 4), (2, 1, 4, 3), (2, 3, 1, 4), (2, 3, 4, 1), (2, 4, 1, 3), (2, 4, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2, 4), (3, 1, 4, 2), (3, 2, 1, 4), (3, 2, 4, 1), (3, 4, 1, 2), (3, 4, 2, 1), (4, 1, 2, 3), (4, 1, 3, 2), (4, 2, 1, 3), (4, 2, 3, 1), (4, 3, 1, 2), (4, 3, 2, 1)]
```

Comment: Or simply `list(permutations(range(1, 5), 4))`.

Comment: @wflynny arg, yes. I had a feeling I was overcomplicating things. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the itertools module:

```
import itertools
arr = [1,2,3,4]
print [x for x in itertools.permutations(arr)]
```